# Hey SO, Won't you take Meta.SO domain?

Tags: discussion, domain-names

Hey SO, Won't you take Meta.SO domain? <s>It is available now.</s>

Comment: Why?​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Because it is "meta.so"

Comment: Is so.so taken yet?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, its mine now.....
Jeff, check my profile for my email and I'll give you control of the domain if you want it
,though I only intend to point it to Meta.Stackoverflow.com

Don't believe me? Here is proof, With free hand circles also ![image: Cool image here]

Comment: Isn't this a terrible idea? I mean, what if people legitimately start finding meta.stackoverflow.com using meta.so (or linking through it)...that'll trainwreck some time in the future...

Comment: if(when) SOIS asks for the domain, I will happily give it to them.

Comment: Seriously @Jacob? This is your reasoning? I'm going to shame you publicly on this one. `It most likely is but I'm 15 and that means I refuse to see the consequences,if(when) SOIS asks for the domain, I will happily give it to them. – Jacob 5 secs ago` "I purposely refuse to acknowledge the results of my actions" ... Wow, good job kid. You wonder why that gets pointed out about the young, it's because those of us over 30 (twice yours) realize that we're still incompetent even at this age.

Comment: I edited that before, but @drachenstern has a great point, that was rather dumb of me to post and all I can do is apologize for it.

Comment: @HansPassant Surprising as it maybe I am a consultant, its scary I have that sort of power. Though that great quote didn't put forth that i am mature enough to handle it.